# What is default size of tile image in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to know that the what is actual size of tile image in windows phone 7.1

Comment: You can have a look here: http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/gg317447.aspx

Comment: In Windows phone 7.1, it is 173 x 173

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394033(v=vs.92).aspx

For WP7 default tile size is **173x173** px for tiles on Start screen, **62x62** for tiles in all apps list.